# Generating a heatmap using R

Tags: r, heatmap

I want a help, I have to make heat map. And I am using the following command in R for generating a matrix, but its returning an error, and I am not able to figure it out.
Can you please tell me what is wrong?

And please also suggest me how to generate a heat map.

```
mat <- matrix(c(100,49.3,45.71,54.29,97.22,68.57,49.3,100,22.54,26.76,50.7,
                33.8,45.71,22.54,100,84.21,44.44,66.67,54.29,26.76,84.21,100,
                52.78,79.17,97.22,50.7,44.44,52.78,100,66.67,68.57,33.8,
                66.67,79.17,66.67,100), nrow = 6, ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE, 
              dimnames = list(c(""A_1HJO","B_2L1W","C_1MHS",
                                "D_1HQY","E_1XU4","F_1JNB""),
              c(("A_1HJO","B_2L1W","C_1MHS","D_1HQY","E_1XU4","F_1JNB"))))

Error: unexpected symbol in "49.3,45.71,54.29,97.22,68.57,49.3,100,22.54,
26.76,50.7,33.8,45.71,22.54,100,84.21,44.44,66.67,54.29,26.76,84.21,100,
52.78,79.17,97.22,50.7,44.44,52.78,100,66.67,68.57,33.8,66.67,79.17,66.67,10"
```

Comment: Is it because of your extra quotation mark in your dimnames list? Also, can you use proper English grammar & punctuation, & SO's markup options? Otherwise, it is very hard for people to read.

Comment: we are not supposed to fix the typo for you, right? are we? `list(c(""A_1HJO"` why two `""` and later `c(("A_1HJO",` why two `((`

Answer (score 0):

Use this to create your matrix:

```
mat <- matrix(c(100,49.3,45.71,54.29,97.22,68.57,49.3,100,22.54,26.76,50.7,
                33.8,45.71,22.54,100,84.21,44.44,66.67,54.29,26.76,84.21,100,
                52.78,79.17,97.22,50.7,44.44,52.78,100,66.67,68.57,33.8,
                66.67,79.17,66.67,100), nrow = 6, ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE, 
              dimnames = list(c("A_1HJO","B_2L1W","C_1MHS",
                                "D_1HQY","E_1XU4","F_1JNB"),
                              c("A_1HJO","B_2L1W","C_1MHS","D_1HQY","E_1XU4","F_1JNB")))
```

Then:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
gg=melt(mat)
ggplot(gg, aes(x=Var1,y=Var2,fill=value))+
  geom_tile()+
  scale_fill_gradient(low="#ffffaa",high="#cc0000")
```

Produces this. Is this what you had in mind?

[image]